# Satisfiability in greater languages

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let $\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{L}'$ two languages in first order logic such that $\mathcal{L}\subset \mathcal{L}'$, $\Gamma \subseteq Form_{\mathcal{L}}$ and $\varphi \in Form_{\mathcal{L}}$. Prove that if $\Gamma \vdash_{\mathcal{L}'} \varphi$ then $\Gamma \vdash_{\mathcal{L}}\varphi$.

In my book, there is a proof when $\mathcal{L}'$ is an extension of $\mathcal{L}$ with only constant symbols, but this is the general case.

I am trying to proceed by contraposition. In case of $\Gamma \nvdash_{\mathcal{L}}\varphi$, then by the Completeness Theorem $\Gamma \nvDash_{\mathcal{L}}\varphi$ so $\Gamma \cup \{\neg \varphi\}$ is satisfiable.

There I stuck because I suspect that being satisfiable in $\mathcal{L}$ implies being satisfiable in $\mathcal{L}'$ but I don't know how to prove it or even it is true.
Possible answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Intuitively, the greater language adds new symbols but the formula are in the restricted one. But the underlying logic (axioms+rules) does not change.

Comment: More formally, by Soundness the antecedent implies $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$ and thus by Completeness the consequent follows.